# unlock the tablet

Tags: applications, tablet

tablet has been locked by attempting many times pattern password. and now tablet has been asking for username and password but we don't know the username and password.the code of the tablet is AGP007
                                                 A0313

Comment: version of android & model of tablet??

Answer (score 0):

If your tablet has root access and ADB debugging enabled then you can consider trying [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ti6QLmDZc8) video for by passing android lock screen.

And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYdkgO1KHmk) one too. Without root.